# How to properly install and set up Flambe?

Tags: html, flash, haxe, flambe

I have followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/aduros/flambe/wiki/Installation), created a new project and tried to run it but all I got was a black web page. I'm not sure if the build command worked properly (I've never done it before).

Then I tried downgrading haxe to 3.1.3 and reinstall Flambe, like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448244/flambe-html-compile-issue). I still get a black page when trying to run the project. Here is the result of using the build command in console (after the downgrade):

```
Building: build/web
haxe -main urgame.Main -lib flambe -cp src -dce full -debug --no-opt --no inline -D html -D js-es5 -D js-flatten --macro flambe.platform.ManifestBuilder.use("build/web/assets") -D source-map-content -js build/web/targets/main-html.js

Building: build/web/targets/main-flash.swf
haxe -main urgame.Main -lib flambe -cp src -dce full -debug --no-opt --no-inline --macro flambe.platform.ManifestBuilder.use("build/web/assets") --flash strict -swf-header 640:480:60:000000 -D fdb -D advanced-telemetry -swf-version 11.2 -swf build/web/targets/main-flash.swf

C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:761: characters 13-14 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : Unknown<0> } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:761: characters 13-14 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:101: characters 10-90 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : format.agal.Swizzle, index : Int, access : Unknown<0> } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:103: characters 9-136 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : format.agal.Swizzle, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:591: characters 12-13 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:591: characters 12-13 : For function argument 'src'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:598: characters 15-16 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:598: characters 15-16 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:599: characters 14-15 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:599: characters 14-15 : For function argument 'src'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:623: characters 8-9 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:623: characters 8-9 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:568: characters 18-19 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:568: characters 18-19 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:569: characters 3-8 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:573: characters 18-19 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:573: characters 18-19 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:574: characters 3-8 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:500: characters 18-77 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : Unknown<0> } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:500: characters 18-77 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:501: characters 18-77 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : Unknown<0> } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:501: characters 18-77 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:502: characters 18-77 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : Unknown<0> } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:502: characters 18-77 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:503: characters 15-74 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : Unknown<0> } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:503: characters 15-74 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:524: characters 12-30 : Void should be format.agal.Opcode
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:524: characters 12-30 : For function argument 'x'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:525: characters 12-52 : Void should be format.agal.Opcode
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:525: characters 12-52 : For function argument 'x'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:526: characters 12-52 : Void should be format.agal.Opcode
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:526: characters 12-52 : For function argument 'x'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:507: characters 18-77 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : Unknown<0> } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:507: characters 18-77 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:508: characters 18-77 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : Unknown<0> } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:508: characters 18-77 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:509: characters 15-74 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : Unknown<0> } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:509: characters 15-74 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:542: characters 12-31 : Void should be format.agal.Opcode
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:542: characters 12-31 : For function argument 'x'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:543: characters 12-53 : Void should be format.agal.Opcode
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:543: characters 12-53 : For function argument 'x'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:639: characters 5-9 : a1 : format.agal.Reg -> r1 : format.agal.Reg -> r2 : format.agal.Reg -> Void should be a2 : format.agal.Reg -> a : format.agal.Reg -> b : format.agal.Reg -> Null< format.agal.Opcode>
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:639: characters 5-9 : Cannot unify return types
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:639: characters 5-9 : Void should be Null<format.agal.Opcode>
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:639: characters 5-9 : Void should be format.agal.Opcode
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:649: characters 4-11 : dst : format.agal.Reg -> a : format.agal.Reg -> b : format.agal.Reg -> format.agal.Opcode should be Void
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:633: characters 3-7 : Void should be dst : format.agal.Reg -> a : format.agal.Reg -> b : format.agal.Reg -> format.agal.Opcode
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:668: characters 20-21 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:668: characters 20-21 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:669: characters 14-15 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:669: characters 14-15 : For function argument 'src'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:675: characters 19-20 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:675: characters 19-20 : For function argument 'r'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:676: characters 8-9 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:676: characters 8-9 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:677: characters 49-50 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:677: characters 49-50 : For function argument 'a'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:684: characters 9-10 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:684: characters 9-10 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:704: characters 49-101 :  { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : Unknown<0> } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:704: characters 49-101 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:704: characters 3-7 : Void should be dst : format.agal.Reg -> v : format.agal.Reg -> format.agal.Opcode
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:712: characters 8-9 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:712: characters 8-9 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:742: characters 23-27 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:742: characters 23-27 : For function argument 'pt'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:188: characters 13-65 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Unknown<1>, index : Int, access : Unknown<0> } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:188: characters 13-65 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:200: characters 14-15 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:200: characters 14-15 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:201: characters 8-9 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:201: characters 8-9 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:206: characters 12-13 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Array<format.agal.C>, index : Int, access : { t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C } } should be format.agal.Reg
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:206: characters 12-13 : For function argument 'dst'
C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:233: characters 10-156 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : format.agal.Swizzle, index : Int, access : Null<{ t : format.agal.RegType, offset : Int, comp : format.agal.C }> } should be format.agal.Reg
```

Is the build command working properly ?

Why am I seeing a black page when running the project using the "flambe serve" command ?

Alternatively, do you know where can I find up-to-date instructions of installing Flambe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors seem to be indentical with [this issue report](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/format/issues/41). So it seems like the solution is to either downgrade the `format` library to `3.2.0` or to get the latest `format` and `hxsl` versions (or at least whatever those were at the time the issue was closed).

Comment: Thanks, I think that it works now. When I run it I see this airplane moving but I can't see any Default/Flash/Html5 links, like those that appear in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0eMZCQjhf4#t=3m44s) . Any idea why ?

Comment: @Robert777 May I ask how you resolved the issue? I am having precisely the same issue. However `haxelib install format 3.2.0` does not seem to be enough because I instead get a different error when building: `C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\flambe/git/src/flambe/platform/flash/FlashMouse.hx:52: characters 17-45 : Only inline or read-only (default, never) fields can be used as a pattern`

Comment: Still not sure why I am getting the FlashMouse.hx error, but if I don't try to build "flash", then the "html" seems to build OK. `flambe build html --debug`.

Comment: I think that error comes from the fact that Flambe is not Haxe 3.3+ (or even 3.2, not sure) compatible. Try downgrading Haxe: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flambe/ep3aDOR7CIA