# Trying to create a new haxe flambe project - Error: should be format.agal.Reg error

Tags: html, haxe, flambe

I mostly followed [this instructions](https://github.com/markknol/flambe-guide/wiki) for installing Haxe, Node, and Flambe on my Mac, with the addition of the following patches:

- [CanvasTextureRoot.hx](https://github.com/aduros/flambe/blob/ec084011873cf16635f4e2a77cc0d2dc6c58625d/src/flambe/platform/html/CanvasTextureRoot.hx)
- [HtmlAssetPackLoader.hx](https://github.com/aduros/flambe/blob/ec084011873cf16635f4e2a77cc0d2dc6c58625d/src/flambe/platform/html/HtmlAssetPackLoader.hx)
- [HtmlExternal.hx](https://github.com/aduros/flambe/blob/ec084011873cf16635f4e2a77cc0d2dc6c58625d/src/flambe/platform/html/HtmlExternal.hx)

I can run existing Flambe apps just fine with `flambe serve` and `flambe run --debug`, but when I try to make my own (via `flambe new projectName`) and run that, I get a long list of errors like the following:

```
haxe --connect 6000 -main urgame.Main -lib flambe -cp src -dce full -debug --no-opt --no-inline --macro flambe.platform.ManifestBuilder.use("build/web/assets") --flash-strict -swf-header 640:480:60:000000 -D fdb -D advanced-telemetry -swf-version 11.2 -swf build/web/targets/main-flash.swf
/usr/local/lib/haxe/hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:761: characters 13-14 : { t : format.agal.RegType, swiz : Null<Array<format.agal.C>>, index : Int, access : Unknown<0> } should be format.agal.Reg
/usr/local/lib/haxe/hxsl/2,0,5/hxsl/AgalCompiler.hx:761: characters 13-14 : For function argument 'dst'
```

I'm not sure what to make of this. An error in my installation?

For reference, here are the versions of the stuff I used:

- haxe -version: 3.2.1
- flambe --version: 4.1.0
- npm -version: 3.3.12

Thanks.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/38092253/2631715 help?

Comment: Hmmm. How would one update the `format` and `hxsl`?

Comment: @Gama11, I ran `sudo haxelib update format`, and it did return `format is up to date`. How do I update `hxsl`?

Comment: `haxelib update hxsl`?

Comment: Thanks. I just did that. Says `Installing dependency format. You already have format version 3.2.1 installed`, which I take it means it's up to date? Anyways, I checked the directories, there's a 2,0,6, but the error is checking 2,0,5.

Comment: Is 2.0.6 the active version? `haxelib list hxsl` should have `2.0.6` in square brackets. If it's not, run `haxelib set hxsl 2.0.6`.

Comment: Yup, it is: `hxsl: 2.0.3 2.0.5 [2.0.6]`.

Comment: The instructions says you need to install hxsl 2.0.3 ?